# My Rmd file keeps getting error message saying that "You are passing a function as global data."

Tags: r, ggplot2, compiler-errors, r-markdown

enter code here

```
#install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)
#install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
#install.packages("magrittr")
library(magrittr)
```

This above code is my file environment and somehow it keeps getting error message "You are passing a function as global data. Have you misspelled the 'data' argument in ggplot."

My data visualization code is

```
str(data)
ggplot(data, aes(y=wage, x=exp1, color=female))+
  geom_jitter()
```

and this is just very simple code but does not compile as html but codes themselves run without any bugs on RStudio.

Plz help me....

Comment: `data` is not a good name for a dataset as it's also the name of a function (try `?data`). My guess: You have a dataset called `data` in your work space but you missed to define it in your RMD file.

Comment: So I change the name of the dataset but it keeps getting error without any messages like "(cross mark) Line 22"... my Rstudio and pc are both up-to-date..

Comment: Simply renaming will (in general) not solve the issue. As I said, from your error message **my guess** is that the RMD does not render as you forgot to read your data in the RMD. An RMD is rendered in a fresh R session, i.e. datasets or packages which you have loaded in your Working Space are no available in the RMD. Hence, you have to put the code to load packages and data inside your RMD.